# Tomcat server.xml locations

Tags: xml, tomcat

I was wondering if it would be possible to add a server.xml into a META-INF folder for tomcat to use. I know that this is possible for the context.xml. If this is not possible are there any ways, project side, to add a resource to the server.xml. The reason I am curious is because if this is possible it would make my general tomcat server.xml cleaner and would make deployments much smoother. If there are any clarifications that are needed just ask.

Or would it be possible to have the equivalent of a resource in the context.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the server.xml file can be thought of as being a global version of the context.xml and cannot be overriden. So to add a resource you just add it to the context.xml like you would the server.